# I am not able to use Start Debugging option in visual studio code

Tags: c++, c, json, gcc, visual-studio-code

I am a noob in coding field and this is my first time I hope I am trying to put question *properly* on stack overflow.

It is always asking to configure launch.json but adding any configuration didn't solve my problem.
My launch.json right now looks like this:-

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]``
    }
  
]}
```

and whenever building it right directly from launch.json I get this message error :-

```
 "launch:program 'enter program name, for example /home/prabhav/Documents/a.out' does not exist.
```

[these are some of the options given for adding configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ84t.png)

Comment: Visual Studio Code is just an editor with plugins. Why do you use it without knowing basics? Use any IDE, for example Visual Studio Community and you get a compiler and a debugger from the box.

Comment: Read the doc about C++ and VSC and your compiler of choice and follow it to the letter, and other wise look at all the `[visual-studio-code] [c++]` questions on here on SO. Not very likely you are the first with this problem, almost daily we get this question